# Magento + Varnish - Logic for stores that open and close at specific Times

Tags: php, ajax, magento, caching, varnish

I recently deployed my Magento site and started using Varnish on it.

However, we do have some PHP logic that place an open and close button on each of the stores (they are open on working times), and after it`s closed it should received any orders.
Also, we have logics on the buttons 'Add to Cart', to inform the customer when the store is opened.

The issue here is that if I serve the pages with VArnish, the loading time indeed is marvelous, however when the store gets opened (or closed), the page is not refreshed (of course).

Which would be a best practice in this case?

- Write an AJAX logic to obtain these dynamic information from the backend
- Run Varnish Purge for all pages that have this logic, by the time the store is opened
- Have a low TTL set (this will reduce Cache Hit).

Thank you very much for the help.

Best Regards,
Mauricio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about storing the open and close times of each store in the html and use javascript to show the current status to the user? That way you can use the cache and still have the dynamic parts that you mentioned.

Example (will not work, mostly pseudo code):

```
<p id="open" data-open-start="8:00 UTC" data-open-end="16:00 UTC">We are open between 8:00 UTC and 16:00 UTC</p>

<script>
  // assuming JQuery
  var open_start_time = [get data-open-start-time and parse it]
  var open_end_time = [get data-open-end-time and parse it]
  // some time zone conversions...
  if (currentTime >= open_start_time && currentTime <= open_end_time) {
    $('p#open').text('we are open!');
  } else {
    $('p#open').text('sorry, we are closed!');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Sven, I'm working in this idea.

In terms of easiness and working, don't you think that it would be nice for me to return via AJAX/JSON only:
 - RestaurantID
 - Status,

Then I can build my JS logic with the IDS and show/hide, change whatever I like.

Thank you for the help.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes you could do that, too. But for the use-case you mentioned I don't think that it is needed. You can encode the absolute opening and closing times in the (cached) HTML, parse it on the client-side via Javascript and show if the restaurant is currently open based on the client-side time and the static encoded data. No AJAX-requests needed.

Comment: Outstanding solution Sven. I'm implementing this way you described, just accomodated to my needs. Thansk man :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still cache the full page, the only solution is to update your Magento to set a special [HTTP header "Expires"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) for each page served. This header allow Varnish to expire cache when the date is over.

So you will need to set the value of the next opening if shop is currently closed and the other way around.

Comment: I have a logic on all Add to Cart buttons on the site, so I think this would drastically reduce my Cache-hits for Varnish, as it has the logic on Category, Product, CMS, Search.. so on.
I will try to add the JS and validate the hours on the html