# .hover not working for element where I dynamically assign a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onhover

I'm implementing a solution based on my previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308080/magento-varnish-logic-for-stores-that-open-and-close-at-specific-times), which its main objective is to check, in Magento, if a store is opened or not. IF it's opened, fine. If it's not, it should deactivate the 'Add to Cart' button and hover a text with the working hours.

This solution does:

1. Get current time on the server via AJAX
2. Check a condition using this time
3. Based on the results of the above, it assigns or not a class to a button element.

However, from my testing I'm seeing that when I try to hover an element which had a class dynamically added via `$(this).addClass('btn-closed');` - it does not work. If I try to hover by matching a class which already exists on the element it works fine (however it won't work as a solution for me due to the logic).

```
// funcao para acertar as classes dos botoes aberto fechado
 $j.get('/restaurante/hora', function(data) {
        $j('#now').val(data);
        // Box de Sugestoes
        $j("#products-grid-QD .btn-cart").each( function() {
            //alert($j(this).attr('tipo') + " " +  $j(this).attr('abre1') + " " + $j(this).attr('fecha1') + " " + $j(this).attr('abre2') + " " + $j(this).attr('fecha2') + " " + $j('#now').val())
            if (checkinrange($j(this).attr('tipo'), $j(this).attr('abre1'),$j(this).attr('fecha1'),$j(this).attr('abre2'),$j(this).attr('fecha2'),$j('#now').val())) {
                $j(this).removeClass('btn-fechado');
            } else {
                $j(this).addClass('btn-fechado');
                $j(this).removeAttr('onclick');
                $j(".commentBtn").text('Fechado');

            }

        });
    }); 


    $j(document).ready(function(){
        $j('.btn-fechado').hover(function() {               
           $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
         }, function() {
           $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");

         });
    });




<button type="button" onclick="btnComprar(<?php echo $_help['store_id']; ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>', '<?php echo $_help['nome'];?>')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')" tipo="<?php echo $_help['tipo'];?>" abre1="<?php echo $_help['abre1'];?>" fecha1="<?php echo $_help['fecha1'];?>" abre2="<?php echo $_help['abre2'];?>" fecha2="<?php echo $_help['fecha2'];?>" >
                                    <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span>
                                </button>
                                <span class="commentBtn"></span>
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does this:

1. Wait for DOM ready
2. Select all elements with class `.btn-fechado`
3. Bind them hover event.

You should bind the event when you assign the class, or use live binding for the events.

Binding when class assigned:

```
$j(this).addClass('btn-fechado')
  .hover(function() {
    $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
  }, function() {
    $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
  });
```

Using live binding:

```
$j(document).on("mouseover", '.btn-fechado', function() {               
  $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
});
$j(document).on("mouseout", '.btn-fechado', function() {
  $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");
});
```

You may replace `$j(document)` for a smaller container.

Comment: `live` is deprecated by `on` though.

Comment: [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gn4EJ/) using the `.on()` feel free to take the code from there. :)

Comment: Thanks Diego! That worked just fine :)
By assigning the hover event when I'm adding the class it work just fine.

Thank you all for the contributions and sorry for taking too much time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid doing this by giving the button itself an id and then use

```
$('#yourButton').addClass('yourClass');
$('#yourButton').on('hover', function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use delegation:

```
$j(document).on('hover','.btn-fechado',function() {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try `hover` with `jquery live`

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.btn-fechado').live('hover',function() {               
       $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "show"}, "slow");
     }, function() {
       $j(this).next(".commentBtn").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "fast");

     });
});
```

with jquery live method you have not bind / unbind dom.
for more info visit.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: live is depreciated for jquery 1.7+, use 'on' instead